# Making a container the same size as it's sibling container without relative/absolute positioning

Tags: html, css

I want the ".on-the-left" container to be the same size as the ".on-the-right" container, without using relative or absolute position.

This is the visual result I want: https://jsfiddle.net/NicoZZZ/osbL16z9/28/

This is what I *consider avoiding*, if I found a clean alternative:

```
.on-the-left {
  position: relative;
}

.container-child {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Please share your codes.

Comment: Please check [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @SatoTakeru Please notice that I have shared my code with a jsfiddle

Comment: You should share essential information *embedded* in your question, not behind a link. Note that you can create a Stack Snippet using the editor toolbar

Comment: So do you want to make the `side-container`s to have same height with minimum height?

Comment: without absolute?

Comment: @SatoTakeru yes the same height, exactly, even if the left container is empty.

Comment: What determines the desired height?

Comment: The content of the container on the right.

Comment: In default, the heights are same with maximum height.

Comment: You can do it without any `position` styling.

Comment: @I modified my question. (I Inverted "on-the-left" and "on-the-right")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this meet all requirements, but the code below produce the same result without the `relative` or `absolute` positioning.

```css
.container-parent {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-auto-rows: fit-content(1em);

    background: pink;
}

.on-the-left {
    background: lightblue;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.on-the-right {
    background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class='container-parent'>
    <div class='side-container on-the-left'>
      <div class='container-child'>
        <p>Some text</p>
        <p>Some text</p>
        <p>Some text</p>
        <!-- After this point you should scroll to see "more text -->
        <p>More text</p>
        <p>More text</p>
        <p>More text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='side-container on-the-right'>
      <p>Some text</p>
      <p>Some text</p>
      <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: It's nice answer.

Comment: @Baro, will you describe how `grid-auto-rows` work?